# using union all then all time getting only two columns at a time

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am unable to get team id and user_type every time getting two columns only

```
SELECT `dev_user`.first_name,`dev_user`.user_id FROM `dev_test_teams_athlete` LEFT JOIN dev_user ON dev_test_teams_athlete.user_id = dev_user.user_id UNION ALL SELECT `dev_user`.first_name, `dev_test_team`.user_id as coach_id FROM `dev_user` RIGHT JOIN dev_test_team ON dev_test_team.user_id = dev_user.user_id UNION ALL SELECT dev_test_team.team_id,dev_test_teams_athlete.user_id as athlete FROM `dev_test_team` LEFT JOIN `dev_test_teams_athlete` ON `dev_test_team`.`team_id` = `dev_test_teams_athlete`.`team_id`
```

this is result when using **union all**  keyword with query

i am getting result like that which is unwanted result

[image]

my dev_test_team table is

[image]

my dev_test_teams_athlete table is

[image]

my dev_user table is

[image]

finally i want result like that as describe in the image

[image]

1st   i want answer like that

```
-------------------------------------------
    user_id | first_name | user_type | team_id
    -------------------------------------------
    480         coach1       3          1
    472         coach2       3          2
    465         coach3       3          3

    380         athlete1     4          1 
    375         athlete2     4          2
    479         athlete3     4          3
    464         athlete4     4          3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    `x`.`team_id`, `du`.`first_name`, `du`.`user_type`, `x`.`team_id`
FROM(
    SELECT `team_id`, `user_id` FROM `dev_test_team`

    UNION ALL

    SELECT `team_id`, `user_id` FROM `dev_test_teams_athlete`
) `x`
LEFT JOIN `dev_user` `du` ON `du`.`user_id` = `x`.`user_id`
```

============================================================

Try it.

Comment: sir, user id not showing and team_id column name two times showing

Comment: sir, i am asking to you for second question answer please answer it

Comment: sir, one question answer is left reply me please

Comment: just put `x`.`user_id` before `x`.`team_id`, `du`.`first_name`, `du`.`user_type`, `x`.`team_id`

Comment: Use group by if your not wanna show team id in two time